# meow bottom navigation bar is not recogonised by android studio even after entering dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-bottomnav

it giving me error <meow.meowbottomnavigation.MeowBottomNavigation
/>
in red, saying missing class even after entering these dependecies.

build.gradel(project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

build.gradel(app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.meowbotm"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.2.0'
}
```

i have also added following lines in gradel properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

i don't know what problem is, in YT and on websites its shows these dependecies are sufficent and meowbottom bar working.

Comment: Please add the error message with stacktrace along with the question here.

Comment: if you have problems with a third party dependency, it is probably going to be more useful to ask on the page where this dependency is hosted

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this tag in your xml file to implement, then it will work. AS you are using 1.2.0 version.

```
<com.etebarian.meowbottomnavigation.MeowBottomNavigation
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btm_nav"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:mbn_backgroundBottomColor="@color/purple_200"
    app:mbn_circleColor="@color/white"
    app:mbn_selectedIconColor="@color/purple_200"
    app:mbn_defaultIconColor="@color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add:

```
jcenter()" settings.gradle->dependencyResolutionManagement->repositories
```

like the img [Failed to resolve: com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5IBQ.png)